# "Expand All" button in a drill down report canceling another feature

Tags: reporting-services

I have a main report that shows a bar chart for the sales per country. once I click on a country bar, a drill down report shows a (+/-) list of all countries toggled by the country name, with only the clicked country expanded, while the others are collapsed.

I was asked by the client to add an "Expand All" button to allow them to expand all countries detail at once. However, when I added this button, the first functionality was lost.

In the initialToggleState Expression of the toggle textbox country I used:
=iif(Fields!country_ID.Value=Parameters!param_Country_ID.Value OR Parameters!paramExpandOrCollapse.Value = "Expand" ,true, false)

Could I have both functionalities working without one canceling the other?

Comment: What is the default value of the `paramExpandOrCollapse` parameter? Also, initial toggle state only affects what is toggled when the report is first loaded, after that, you will have to update the **Hidden** property under **Visibility** in the properties of the item(s).

Comment: The default value for paramExpandOrCollapse.Value = "Collapse". When the report is first loaded, all countries are collapsed, even the one where:
Fields!country_ID.Value=Parameters!param_Country_ID.Value, and supposed to be expanded. The "Expand all" textbox does not work either.

Comment: You will need to have your `iif` added to the **visibility** of the group or the row that you want to show/hide. I believe the initial toggle state property only affects whether the toggle button shows a +/- when loaded.